# Roughly how long does a 1TB content migration from Sharepoint 2007 to Office365 take using a tool

Tags: migration, content-migration

Roughly how long does a 1TB content migration from Sharepoint 2007 to office 365 take using a tool such Sharegate or Metalogix?

I only need to know a rough transfer time from past experiences.  If you have done any size of transfers could please give size, tool and time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MetaVisTechs content migration software I transferred just under 250gb in 24 ish hours on a 10Mbit line.

Then I did 2.5gb in about 25minutes.

It depends on the data and the complexity of the managed metadata.

http://www.metavistech.com

Comment: thanks for replying. was this sharepoint 2007 to office365? how was the tool? have you got any recommendations on tools?

Comment: The tool made it very easy and it was indeed SharePoint 2007 to Office 365. There where zero issues and I did it in a single weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!.

Before I answer I just want to let you know that I actually work for MetaVis so my post is a little biased :)

From a MetaVis perspective I can't tell you exactly what to expect as the tool relies on the internet connection that you are using. What I would recommend is downloading & installing MetaVis to figure out the average speed that you will get.

You can get a free trial here http://bit.ly/105Kkfq

Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the others here, there are too many factors that play into the speed of a migration. The bandwidth is definitely a big one, especially going to Office 365 since we have no control over the server itself.
Then you have the amount of properties and of course the number of versions in the version history. 
Many did not realize that having 10 versions of a 10MB document is actually 100MB (estimate). This means transferring all of that information with the right properties over.

Most tools will migrate at fairly the same speed when going to Office 365, you should simply look at the the one that works best for you whichever it is. I am a little biased too as Gemma is, as I work for Sharegate http://en.share-gate.com. And if you have time, we created some funny videos worth checking out completely unrelated to migration :P http://en.share-gate.com/funny

..And my super awesome powers just noticed the date on the post haha

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old thread but i tough i would have to point that things have changed in the past year for migration in O365. Speed varies a lot depending on the type of content, versions and metadata attached to it.

[Microsoft Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-Migration-Speed-21cfb6a0-fa4c-44c6-9a39-0f45e85e371f)